# Segmentation fault occurring with child pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm currently working on custom thread scheduler project that uses pthreads in C. I have been struggling conceptually with it but am finally getting the behavior I expect to see, save for the segmentation fault.

My job is to register five child threads and schedule each one based on the order of their IDs stored in an array. What I do is call `pthread_mutex_lock` and tell whichever child thread that is not to be scheduled first to wait. I do some stuff to my counter to keep track of when the next child should be scheduled and after one child thread increments counter to five it should wake up other threads and do the same thing for as many times as main loop is defined.

all variables:

```
#define NTHREADS         5             /* Number of child threads        */
#define NUM_LOOPS  10             /* Number of local loops          */
#define SCHEDULE_INTERVAL 1            /* thread scheduling interval     */

#define errexit(code,str) fprintf(stderr,"%s: %s\n",(str),strerror(code));exit(1);

int schedule_vector[NTHREADS];        /* The thread schedule vector      */

int flag = 0;
pthread_cond_t cv;                   // condtitional variable
pthread_mutex_t mtx;               // mutex semaphore 1
int globalcounter = 0;
int currentThread;
#define TASK_LIMIT  6
```

here is parent thread:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  int       i;                        
  int       worker;                     
  int       ids[NTHREADS];              
  int       errcode;                 
  int       *status;                    
  int       policy;                     

  pthread_t threads[NTHREADS];        

  /* Create child threads --------------------------------------------- */
  for (worker = 0; worker < NTHREADS; worker++)
  {
    ids[worker] = worker;              

    printf("creating child thread using id %d\n", worker);

    /* Create a child thread ----------------------------------------- */
    pthread_create (                 
      &threads[worker],    
      NULL,                 
      my_thread,          
      &ids[worker]);      
    }

    /* Initialize the thread schedule vector  -------------------------- */
    schedule_vector[0] = 0;      /* First thread to be executed (0)      */
    schedule_vector[1] = 1;      /* Second thread to be exceuted (1)     */
    schedule_vector[2] = 2;      /* Third thread to be executed (2)      */
    schedule_vector[3] = 3;      /* Fourth thread to be executed (3)     */
    schedule_vector[4] = 4;      /* Fifth thread to be executed (4)      */

    signal(SIGALRM, clock_interrupt_handler);
    alarm(SCHEDULE_INTERVAL);
    printf("handler set up\n");

    /* Reap the threads as they exit ----------------------------------- */
    for (worker = 0; worker < NTHREADS; worker++)
    {
      /* Wait for thread to terminate --- */
      if (errcode=pthread_join(threads[worker],(void *) &status))
      { errexit(errcode,"pthread_join"); }

      /* Check thread's exit status and release its resources -------- */
      if (*status != worker)
      {
        fprintf(stderr,"thread %d terminated abnormally\n",worker);
        exit(1);
      }
    }

    /* The main (parent) thread terminates itself ---------------------- */
    return(0);
  }
```

Here is the child thread function:

```
void *my_thread(void * arg)
{
  long int i;                  
  long int counter;      
  int myid=*(int *) arg;  
  counter = 0;
  printf("\nI am thread #%d\n\n", myid);

  /* Main loop ------------------------------------------ */
  for (i = 0; i < NUM_LOOPS; i++)
  {

        currentThread = myid;
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        while(myid != schedule_vector[flag]){
          pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mtx);
        }
        counter++;
        globalcounter = counter;


    printf("Thread: %d is running ...\n", myid);
    usleep(100000);
  }
  return arg;
}
```

and here is my interrupt handler:

```
void clock_interrupt_handler(void)
{

  printf("scheduler started ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ \n");
  if (currentThread == schedule_vector[flag]) {
    printf("scheduled thread received: thread %d, and it's counter is at %d\n", currentThread, globalcounter);
    while(globalcounter < TASK_LIMIT){
    if(globalcounter == 5){
      flag++;
      pthread_cond_broadcast(&cv);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    alarm(SCHEDULE_INTERVAL);
    }
  } else {
    printf("unscheduled thread received, putting thread %d  with count %d to sleep...\n", currentThread, globalcounter);
    alarm(SCHEDULE_INTERVAL);

  }


}
```

This is the output:

```
scheduler started ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
scheduled thread received: thread 0, and it's counter is at 1
Thread: 0 is running ...
Thread: 0 is running ...
Thread: 0 is running ...
Thread: 0 is running ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It basically repeats this behavior, but for each thread. I'd like to understand what is exactly causing the seg fault

Comment: Please also post the code that create and start the threads.

Comment: @fluter Added the parent

Comment: @fluter Okay, that's everything. Sorry...I should have put that in from the get go...

Comment: Pthreads functions and stdio functions are not async-signal-safe.  You must not call them from an interrupt handler.

Comment: Additionally, you seem to intend that the `pthread_cond_broadcast()` and `pthread_mutex_unlock()` calls in your signal handler pair with the `pthread_mutex_lock()` in your thread function, but even if these functoins were async-signal-safe, it seems overly optimistic to rely on such a pairing.

Comment: @JohnBollinger May you elloborate why this assumption is overly optimistic? And as note the segmentation fault still occurs without the print calls. Could I assume this may be the point you were trying to make between the two mutex calls?

Comment: Mutex, conditional vars aren't initialized.

Comment: @ZFN7, a process-directed signal can be delivered to any thread in the process that does not have it blocked.  `pthread_cond_wait()` does not cause any signals to be blocked.  But really, that's all secondary.  You must not call pthreads functions in a signal handler at all.  They are not async-signal safe.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, so are you saying that the fact that I have not async-signal safe components inside my handler this could be a cause to the segmentation fault?

Comment: @ZFN7, the behavior of functions that are not async-signal safe is **unspecified** when they are called from a signal handler.  It is entirely possible that under some circumstances, a segfault could occur.  Inasmuch as your segfault seems to correlate with your `pthread_cond_broadcast()` call, that doesn't seem so far-fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pthread_mutex_lock/pthread_mutex_unlock do not pair.

The correct code looks like

```
pthread_mutex_lock()
pthread_cond_broadcast()
pthread_mutex_unlock()

pthread_mutex_lock()
pthread_cond_wait()
pthread_mutex_unlock()
```